# Keep some elements together in writeLines

Tags: r, text

I'd like to use `writeLines()` to write a set of character vectors to separate lines in an unformatted text file. However, some of the vectors have multiple elements, while some don't. Example:

```
a <- "string 1"
b <- "string 2"
c <- c("string 3a","string 3b","string 3c")
```

Using `writeLines()` gives:

```
> writeLines(c(a,b,c))
string 1
string 2
string 3a
string 3b
string 3c
```

whereas I'd like to see:

```
string 1
string 2
string 3a, string 3b, string 3c
```

is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: One option is `cat(a, b, toString(c), sep="\n", file = "file1.txt")` or to show on console, just remove the `file` argument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `toString`

```
writeLines(sapply(list(a, b, c), toString))
#string 1
#string 2
#string 3a, string 3b, string 3c
```

Comment: I like this. Didn't know about `toString`, so this is helpful in more ways than one!